# How to perform action and not striggering segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have created a segue from view controller A (Task View Controller) to view controller B (Add Task View Controller) that is triggered through a button(add) in view controller A.

I have a problem: If I want create a task in more detail, I will tap on button to show View Controller B, then tap save on View Controller B to done!

But when I want to create a task quickly by text in `UITextField` beside button add. Then tap on Button and the task was created without present View Controller B.

this is my story board with connection inspector: [connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bizji.png)

i try to add if statement (in comment code) but not working

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let identifier = segue.identifier else {return}

         switch identifier {
            case Segue.addTaskVC:

            //   if let taskTitle = inputTF.text, !taskTitle.isEmpty {
            //                // Create Task
            //                let task = Task(context: coreDataManager.managedObjectContext)
            //                
            //                // Configure Task
            //                task.updatedAt = Date()
            //                task.createdAt = Date()
            //                task.title = taskTitle
            //                
            //                updateView()
            //                return
            //            }

                guard let destionation = segue.destination as? AddTaskVC else {return}

                // Configure Context
                destionation.managedObjectContext = coreDataManager.managedObjectContext

            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

this is my action is conected with segue

```
@IBAction func addTaskButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("add Task Button Was Pressed")
    // **Save quickly here**

}
```

is there a way to save quickly and prevent striggering segue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implement [`shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue)
- Return `false` if there is text in the text field
- In `addTaskButtonWasPressed` check also if there is text in the text field. If yes, save the task.